# Python object creation and variable usage

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to make a python script that will prompt the user for two input floats and perform calculations with the input.  Before I can get to that part I am having trouble understanding how to create an object and access it.

I am starting out simple with just one object here called FightingForce to learn the concept I am just take input for creating 1 of these object and trying to print it.

My question is how do I get the user input and store it as a FightingForce object, that is accessible for use in an equation?

```
# Create a fighting force object
class FightingForce(object):
    size = 0
    lethalityCoefficient = 0

    # Class constructor/initilizer
    def __init__(self, size, lethalityCoefficient):
        self.size = size
        self.lethalityCoefficient = lethalityCoefficient

def make_fightingForce(size, lethalityCoefficient):
    fightingForce = FightingForce(size, lethalityCoefficient)
    return fightingForce

# Prevent user from inputting anything other than a float
while True:

    try:
        # Promt user for input and set variables
        size = float(raw_input('Enter the amount of troops: '))
        lethalityCoefficient = float(raw_input('Enter the lethality coefficient: '))

    except ValueError:
        print("Please input a floating point integer greater than zero")
        continue

    else:
        break

# Display results to user
print(fightingForce.size)
raw_input('Press <ENTER> to exit')
```

Currently my code will ask for the two inputs and immediately close after I enter them.  I have tried placing "raw_input('Press  to exit')" in various locations in an attempt to see where it is failing but I am not getting any good results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just instantiate an instance of the FightingForce object inside the loop

```
while True:
    try:
        size = float(raw_input('Enter the amount of troops: '))
        lethalityCoefficient = float(raw_input('Enter the lethality coefficient: '))
        fightingForce = make_fightingForce(size, lethalityCoefficient)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Please input a floating point integer greater than zero")
print(fightingForce.size)
```

Comment: this answers my original question, thanks so much.  I am trying to work through creating multiple fightingForce objects with the loop now.  If the loop executed 2 times I am trying to create fightingForce1 and fightingForce2... Thanks again.

Comment: If you're trying to create multiple FightingForce objects then you should first prompt the user for how many they want to create. Then each iteration of this loop should create a new FightingForce object and add it to a list containing all the FightingForce objects. Break the loop when the list contains as many FightingForce objects as the user wanted.

Comment: excellent idea, I am trying to figure out how to make two of them at the moment then I will work on that.

Comment: I got it working and I owe you and yeniv both much thanks!  Until next time.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating an object of the class in function `make_fightingForce` and returning it from there. Just call this function and take its return value to use it.

Change the last lines to:

```
print(make_fightingForce(size, lethalityCoefficient).size)
```

Comment: This works for creating a single object, and I upvoted for your help (thanks!), but I am looking to be able to create multiple of them based on the value of the loop counter.

Comment: That's not apparent in your original question. And what do you mean by "loop counter"?

Comment: @ alan, sorry if the initial question didn't mention where I was going with it.  I want to basically create fightingForce + str(x) where x is incremented for the number of loop iterations.  Then I want to be able to do fightingForce1.size, fightingForce2.size, etc.